# loop through list of jsons, curl it and save outputs

Tags: json, bash, curl

I have a list of jsons in a file `input.dat` like so (many are utf-8 encoded):

```
{"var1": "laptop", "var2": "new", "var3": "ugly"}
{"var1": "televison", "var2": "old", "var3": "bad"}
{"var1": "cleaner", "var2": "used", "var3": "good"}
{"var1": "Pakman", "var2": "sale", "var3": "thrones"}
```

I have built an api which works with the following curl command:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H 'Authorization: Token 878768' \
--request POST \
--data '{"var1":"test", "var2":"item", "var3":"stack"}' \
"http://<ip_add>:80/endpoint/api/" -o out.dat
```

Id like to loop through all the jsons line by line in the input file and send it to the above curl and save it as separate outputs - taking care that utf-8 is also correctly encoded.

Not exactly sure what is the best way to do this. I think I need to cat the json, pipe it to curl:

```
cat input.dat | curl? -o <outdir/out?>
```

I thought this would be a common problem but I coudnt find a suitable answer on stack :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the file line by line and call `curl`.

```
i=1
while read -r json
do
    curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H 'Authorization: Token 878768' \
        --request POST \
        --data "$json" \
        "http://<ip_add>:80/endpoint/api/" > out.$i.dat
    ((i++))
done < input.dat
```

Comment: Oh thank a tonne. Does this write/append all outputs to `out.dat`?

Comment: a single > is write new each time.  append would be `>> out.dat`.

Comment: Yes. What do you think `> out.dat` does at the end?

Comment: @JeremyFiel It's redirecting the output of the entire loop, not each individual `curl`.

Comment: @barmar oh you're right, just scanned it. :)

Comment: @Barmar but the output does not seem to be in each line?

Comment: The output is whatever the API returns. If it returns multiple lines for each call, that's what you get.

Comment: I've updated the answer to write to separate numbered files.

Comment: @Barmar I prefr the last approach where everything is dumped to a single file.. but my question was that for example when I do a head -n1 on the out.dat file it shows me the entire file, wheras I was expecting -n1 to show the output of only the first call

Comment: If the API only returns 1 line for each call that would work. But if it returns multiple lines, there's no delimiter between them. So writing to separate files simplifies things.